# Make javascript execute after javascript from add-on in firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

I recently installed the add-on leechblock, which keeps track of how long you browse on specific sites and blocks you if you exceed the limits you set for yourself.

Unfortunately the page it shows when blocking a site is pretty ugly, so I set out to make my own html-page to show instead. On this html-page, in addition to a lot of other stuff, there is a link which gets you back to the page where you wanted to go originally (if the block has expired), which looks like this:

```
<a id="lbClickHereLink">back</a></br>
```

This `lbClickHereLink` is then set in the add-on code (in the file browser.js) as follows:

```
    // Update hyperlink to blocked page
    var clickHereLink = doc.getElementById("lbClickHereLink");
    if (clickHereLink != null) {
        clickHereLink.setAttribute("href", blockedURL);
    }
```

Now I am also using this html-page in other contexts (it's basically a to-do list), and I thought it would be really neat to only have this link if I actually got there from a blocked page. (Otherwise it's just empty anyway.)

So I tried this (inside the html-document):

```
<script>
var leechlink = document.getElementById("lbClickHereLink");
if(leechlink.getAttribute("href") == null)
   leechlink.innerHTML = "";
</script>
```

But this doesn't work, because at the time the html-page is loaded, the script from the add-on apparently has not yet been executed. So the link is never there.

So my question is:

Is it possible to get the above script to execute *after* the code from the add-on has been executed?

On a teach-a-man-to-fish side note: Can I get the firefox debugger to show me all the javascript code that's being executed on a page, not just what's in the html-document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since addon scripts run in sandboxes that are difficult (but not impossible) to access it's probably easier to just edit the addon and replace the html page you don't like with something nicer.

Addon XPIs are just zip files mostly containing standard web technologies, javascript, CSS, HTML/XML modulo some browser-specific code.

If you really want to do it without modifying the addon you could probably use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes to the HTML and look for html structures specific to the addon in question.

for the fishing: use the [browser toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox)

Comment: Since I am using the html-file primarily as a to-do list, which I keep editing, incorporating it into the add-on is not really an option. The browser toolbox somehow ignores my breakpoints, but thanks for the tip anyway. I'll look into the mutation observers; that looks like what I had in mind. I just realized I probably could edit the addon to set innerhtml together with href. I was thinking the whole time about how I could take the text away when not needing it, instead of *putting* it there only when I need it.